# Matlab code for generating some signed distance field of some shapes

Tags: matlab, shapes

In order to get a good understanding of my question, please, you may first run the matlab code below. This code can generate the shape for rectangle, ellipse and circle using signed distance if you uncomment the portion corresponding to each shape.

Please, I need a code that can give the shapes in the attached Picture1 below using signed distance. Thank you so much.

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG7Cq.jpg)

```
%%% Signed distance code for generating shapes
clear all;
close all;
clc;
DomainWidth=2;
DomainHight=1;
ENPC=40;   
ENPR=80;
EW = DomainWidth / ENPR;       %  The width of each finite element.
EH = DomainHight / ENPC;        %   The hight of each finite element.
M = [ ENPC + 1 , ENPR + 1 ];
[ x,y ] = meshgrid( EW * [ -0.5 : ENPR + 0.5 ] , EH * [ -0.5 : ENPC + 0.5 ]);
[ FENd.x, FENd.y, FirstNdPCol] = MakeNodes(ENPR,ENPC,EW,EH);
LSgrid.x = x(:); LSgrid.y = y(:);       % The coordinates of Level Set grid 1
cx = DomainWidth/2;
cy= DomainHight/2;
a = cx;
b = 0.8*cy;
%% Generate circle
tmpPhi=  sqrt ( ( LSgrid . x - cx  ) .^2 + ( LSgrid . y  - cy  ) .^2 ) - 
DomainHight/2; 
LSgrid.Phi = -((tmpPhi.')).';
%% Generate ellipse
%   tmpPhi=   ( (LSgrid . x - cx)/a  ) .^2 + (( LSgrid . y  - cy)/(0.8*cy)  ) .^2  - 1;
%  LSgrid.Phi = -((tmpPhi.')).';
%% Generate rectangle
% lower = [cx - 0.5 * DomainWidth, cy - 0.25 * DomainHight];
% upper = [cx + 0.5 * DomainWidth, cy + 0.25 * DomainHight];
% Phi11 =max(LSgrid.x  - upper(1), lower(1) - LSgrid . x );
% Phi11 =max(Phi11,LSgrid.y   - upper(2));
% Phi11 =max(Phi11,lower(2) - LSgrid . y );
% LSgrid.Phi = -Phi11;
%%
FENd.Phi = griddata( LSgrid.x, LSgrid.y, LSgrid.Phi, FENd.x, FENd.y, 'cubic');


figure(10)
% Figure of the full contour plot of the signed distance of the shape
     contourf( reshape( FENd.x, M), reshape(FENd.y , M), reshape(FENd.Phi, M));
      axis equal;  grid on;drawnow; colorbar;
 figure(11)
% Figure of the scaled contour plot showing only the shape
      contourf( reshape( FENd.x, M), reshape(FENd.y , M), reshape(FENd.Phi, M), [0 0] );
      axis equal;  grid on;drawnow; colorbar;
figure(12)
%Figure of the signed distance function 
    h3=surface(x, y, reshape(-LSgrid.Phi , M + 1));  view([37.5  30]);  axis equal;  grid on; 
    set(h3,'FaceLighting','phong','FaceColor','interp', 'AmbientStrength',0.6); light('Position',[0 0 1],'Style','infinite'); colorbar;  
   %% Code for creating nodes    
  function [NodesX, NodesY, FirstNdPCol] = 
  MakeNodes(EleNumPerRow,EleNumPerCol,EleWidth,EleHight)
  [ x , y ]= meshgrid( EleWidth * [ 0 : EleNumPerRow ], EleHight * [0 : EleNumPerCol]);
  FirstNdPCol = find( y(:) == max(y(:)));
  NodesX = x(:); NodesY = y(:);
  end
```

Comment: What does the signed distance define in each shape? What is the result of your current code?

Comment: Inside the shape is positive, outside the shape is negative. I have got an insight into the case 3 in the attached picture. Check here: "https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/423827-matlab-code-for-generating-some-shapes-using-signed-distance?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_view#comment_621969". It remains only case 1 and 2. Thank you so much.